# PouchDB http stack used in cordova based android app?

Tags: cordova, http, cordova-plugins, couchbase, pouchdb

New to [pouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/) world.

1)Plan: Android app with Cordova + pouchDB +SQLite Plugin + SyncGateWay+ Couchbase Server.

2)What does the HTTP stack used by pouchDB javascript for syncing docs?

Thanks

Nithin

Answer (score 1):

When you use PouchDB, you actually don't manage the HTTP stuff yourself. PouchDB communicates directly with CouchDB/CouchbaseSyncGateway/Cloudant/etc. when you call `db.sync()` or `db.replicate()`.

You can set up a Nginx or Apache reverse proxy if you like, but it's also fine to just talk directly to the database.

Comment: Yeah right i wont deal http directly..just curious what http stack is been used to sync internally..just to know its performance or congifuration..

Comment: CouchBaseLite android uses Apache HTTP Stack..similarly what does the PouchDb uses to communicate to CouchbaseSyncGateway?

Comment: PouchDB uses the browser's or embedded webview's HTTP stack.